# I need help understanding why this integral is the probability for winning by switching in the Monty Hall problem

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-function

I need help understanding this probability from the Monty Hall problem. Why does this integral give the probability of winning by switching if the Car is behind 1, Monty shows goat behind 3 and Player picked 2.

[image]

The equation (4) can be viewed in full here:

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.734.2892&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: $Q$ is the probability that, given that the car is behind door 1  (called event $C_1$)  and the player initially picks door 1, that Monty opens door 3 (called event $D_3$ - in the case here the alternative would have been opening door 2).  $Q$ is unknown but supposed to chosen randomly having a prior distribution with density $f_Q$. The integral is a standard application of conditional probability, and with the restricted conditions here in effect says that the actual probability is the expectation of the prior distribution for $Q$

Comment: @John Larson Welcome. Thought I should mention the frequentist solution. A frequentist will randomly choose a door, so probability of selected door has car is 1/3, and probability car is behind one of the other 2 doors is 2/3. After selection, the probabilities are now confidences: 1/3 confidence car behind selected door, and 2/3 confidence behind one of the 2 unselected doors. The presenter kindly opens one of the unselected doors but never one if it has the car behind it. So the 2/3 confidence is now concentrated on the other unselected door. So switching is best.